# Building Boost library on windows 8 using CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, boost, build, codeblocks, bootstrapper

I am trying to install and build Boost libraries on my laptop which runs Windows 8 and CodeBlocks. I am following the steps described in most of the guides that I found on web to no extent.

I downloaded boost 1.57.0 from boost.org and I extracted the library to C:/. From the root library, I run `bootstrap.bat gcc` and I keep obtaining a `Failed to build Boost.Build engine`.

The following is the content of `bootstrap.log`

```
###
### Using 'gcc' toolset.
###

c:\Boost\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\src\engine>if exist bootstrap rd /S /Q       bootstrap 

c:\Boost\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\src\engine>md bootstrap 

c:\Boost\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\src\engine>gcc -DNT -o bootstrap\jam0.exe  command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execcmd.c execnt.c filent.c frames.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathnt.c pathsys.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c md5.c class.c cwd.c w32_getreg.c native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c
```

I cannot understand what is causing the error since the .log doesn't say anything about it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have gcc installed and is it on your path?  CodeBocks is an IDE and may or may not include a compiler.  If you have gcc installed what version is it (run `gcc --version`)?

Comment: I should have specified it before. `gcc --version` returns `gcc.ext (GCC) 4.7.0 20111220 (experimental)`